# Product quantity to nearest Qty Increments multiples when adding to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, qty-increment

We have products as pack. Lets say 8 coke canes. So users can add any quantity as multiple of 8.

For doing this we enabled `Enable Qty Increments` and entered `Qty Increments` as 8. And this functionality works fine.

What we need is user enter any quantity which is not a multiple of 8, quantity should be updated as next nearest 8 multiples.

I checked with any observers available before updating it. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event

```
sales_quote_product_add_after
```

which is triggered before the new items are saved, so that you can use

`$item->getOrigData('qty')` to get the original quantity.

The event has one parameter, items which is an `array`

and you can update it accordingly your inventory.

hope this will work for you.